# Window service running every minutes

Tags: c#, windows

I have a window service which runs every minute. I also used object of `List<User>` (Where User is a my class) to save the list of users. Service did two tasks

1. Fetch the users in from the database and add to object of `List<User>`
2. Send SMS to users and remove the user from object of `List<User>`

I used the `System.Timers.Timer` class to run the service every minutes. But i face the problem that some times service skip some users to send the SMS. So I have doubts on my approach, can anybody tell me I am doing this the right way or I can do this another way?

**Edit**

```
List<User> ListUser = new List<User>();
bool IsReadyToExecute = false;

public Service()
{
    //Main();
    InitializeComponent();
    _timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(_timer_Elapsed);
    _timer.Interval = 1 * 1000;
}
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    MessageLog("Service Start", "Service Start at: " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
    this._timer.Enabled = true;
    _timer.Start();
}
protected override void OnStop()
{
    MessageLog("Service Stop", "Service Stop at: " + DateTime.Now.ToString());         
    this._timer.Enabled = false;
    _timer.Stop();
}
public void _timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageLog("Timer Start", "Call from _timer_Elapsed  at: " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
    this.Main();
}
private void Main()
{
    if (!IsReadyToExecute)
    {
        if (DateTime.Now.Second == 0)
        {
            _timer.Interval = 1 * 60 * 1000;
            IsReadyToExecute = true;
        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }
    }
    if (IsReadyToExecute)
    {
        CreateUser();
        InsertUser();
    }
}
```

Comment: It will be nearly impossible to guess where the problem might be if you don't at least post the relevant timer and SMS sending code. It could be a race condition of sorts. Could be a bug in code. No way to know without seeing code.

Comment: What is the purpose of this line `if (DateTime.Now.Second == 0)` ? Also you should post code that (a) populates the `List<User>` and also code that removes entries from there. Specifically, the code that updates the database to know which users have already been sent a message. It's possible somewhere in there, when the new list is gotten it excludes some users depending on how you fetch/update the status of processed users.

Comment: i used if (DateTime.Now.Second == 0) to call service at 00 second means  for eg. i want call service at 08:05:00 not 08:05:44.

Comment: My question is that, is my approach is fine. Means creating a List of user and add and remove users on it. Or i should use some other apporoch

Comment: Well if your approach isn't working then it's not fine, right? Whether you populate a list, or use a queue, etc., is all good; the issue is HOW you populate, HOW you retrieve and mark items that have been processed, and if a bug in that logic can cause people to get "missed" - which is what I thought you said the problem is, right?

Comment: What I'm saying is, you're asking the wrong question :) The list of users isn't by itself causing people to occasionally not get send an SMS message. Does that make sense?

Comment: okay can you tell me what will happen if at time 05:00, 2000 sms to be send and at 05:01, 3000 sms to be send. When service starts at 05:00 its received the 2000 users with messages from database and start adding it to list. and suppose when 1500th user with message added the 1 minute time complete and _timer_Elapsed event fired. What you thing in that case service will work. Can i avoid this type of situation in any other way

Comment: The proper way to do this is STOP THE TIMER. Let the processing finish. Then start the timer again. That way the requests do not step over each other.

Comment: Then you won't need this nonsense with a 1 second timer that then resets to a 60 second timer and hopes to land at exactly 00 seconds, etc. So -- timer elapses, stop timer, process records, then re-start the timer (for 5 minutes or whatever interval you want to process your queue at). This method will also have the benefit of avoiding any possible race condition, meaning everyone will get a text message.

Comment: okay it seems to be good solution in normal cases, But if 2000 sms take 2 minutes to complete the process then 3000 sms at 05:01 will be skipped. How i can avoid it

Comment: I just told you how to avoid it... if 2000 sms take a 2 minutes, or two hours, it doesn't matter; the timer (stopped) will while they process, and then send the next 3000. That's the point. The timer will not fire while processing is happening, and you won't have this issue!

Comment: All these sms are scheduled accoding to time. I fetch them from database and compare with time. so the sms scheduled at 05:01 should be sent out at 05:01. one minute can be up down

Comment: I think the design of your entire service is outside the scope of questions/answers on StackOverflow. I was giving you pointers how to avoid a race condition in your code. If you have time sensitive messages that must execute at 5:01 exactly, and they can't all get sent out at the same time, it is a different problem than some people not receiving an sms message occasionally. If these are life or death emergency sms messages then you might invest in better hardware, etc. Otherwise for some basic reminder stuff, if it's 1 or 2 minutes late, what is the problem?

Comment: You can also look at `ConcurrentQueue<T>` which is a thread-safe collection and have one timer that populates it and another that just sends messages; that way you can populate the queue continuously and not lose any time; the processing itself should not take that long because all you're doing is sending an email to a phone number, essentially. If that is a bottleneck then think of using multiple mail servers, etc.

Comment: Thanks @DavidKhaykin, I think this will work for me, I will use two timer which will do two different tasks and use this   ConcurrentQueue<T>. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this structure

```
other using .....

using System.Threading;

public partial class YourService : ServiceBase
{
    bool StopMe = false;

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        MessageLog("Service Start", "Service Start at: " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
        this.StopMe = false;
        this.StartTheThread();      
    }
    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        this.StopMe = true; 
    }

    Thread SMSSender;
    private void StartTheThread()
    {
        ThreadStart st = new ThreadStart(DoProcess);
        SMSSender = new Thread(st);
        SMSSender.Start();
    }

    private void DoProcess()
    {
        while(!this.StopMe)
        {
            MessageLog("Timer Start", "Call from thread loop  at: " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
            List<User> ListUser = new List<User>();
            //Code/function to be called to populate ListUser

            foreach(User usr in ListUser)
            {
                //Code/function to be called to send sms here

                if (this.StopMe) break; //stop the thread when stop flag is set
            }


            Thread.Sleep(60*1000); //sleep for 1 minute
        }

        MessageLog("Service Stop", "Service Stop at: " + DateTime.Now.ToString()); 
    }
}
```